# Which Azure AD property (from login response) store as UserId in the database?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Upon successful login with Azure AD (via MSAL 2), I get the following object:

```
environment:"login.windows.net"
homeAccountId:"ID_1.ID_2"
idTokenClaims:Object
    aio:"xxx"
    aud:"xxx"
    exp:1661778482
    iat:1661774582
    idp:"https://sts.windows.net/ID_2"
    iss:"https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID"
    name:"xxx"
    nbf:1661774582
    nonce:"xxx"
    oid:"ID_3"
    preferred_username:"xxx"
    rh:"xxx"
    sub:"xxx"
    tid:"xxx"
    uti:"xxx"
    ver:"xxx"
localAccountId:"ID_3"
name:"xxx"
nativeAccountId:undefined
tenantId:"TENANT_ID"
```

It seems that [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/claims), if I understand correctly, you need to take **idTokenClaims.oid** which is equal to **localAccountId**.
But I thought that if you want real permanent `UserId` to store in database, then you should look at the properties of the user through the Azure portal, and takes its **Object ID** field. I am a bit confused that Azure user's **Object ID** field also existed in the returned object (upon Azure AD login via MSAL). **Object ID** is in the **homeAccountId** field, namely **ID_1**, but for some reason it is followed by a dot and some other incomprehensible **ID_2**, which is present in **idTokenClaims.idp**.

Please tell me what is correct to store in the database as **UserId** in the **CreatedBy** field for an Azure AD user when authorizing through MSAL 2:

1. **idTokenClaims.oid**, aka **localAccountId**?
2. or **ID_1** from **homeAccountId** (which equals to the user's **Object ID**) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object ID i.e. **oid** is the primary claim that you should use as part of a system of records (plus tenant ID i.e. **tid** if you are serving multiple tenants).

**homeAccountId** and **localAccountId** are MSAL SDK specific terms, but they map to claims in the ID token eventually -**homeAccountId** is "oid.tid", while **localAccountId** is simply "oid" as it's only used with ADFS which doesn't have tenancy.

The `idTokenClaims` in the response payload is the actual decoded ID token from Azure AD, and then MSAL adds further useful metadata to the response.

See also:

- [Microsoft identity platform ID tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims).
- [Data access sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api#access-to-data)